# relative path in BAT script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, relative-path, drive

Here is my own program folder on my USB drive:

```
Program\
     run.bat
     bin\
         config.ini
         Iris.exe
         library.dll
         etc.
```

I would like to use `run.bat` to start  `Iris.exe`

I cannot use this: `F:/Program/bin/Iris.exe` like a shortcut, because sometimes it does not attach as drive `F:` (*e.g.* `E:` or `G:`)

What do I need to write in the bat file to work regardless of the drive letter?

I tried this in the BAT file:

```
"\bin\Iris.exe"
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 351):

Use this in your batch file:

```
%~dp0\bin\Iris.exe
```

`%~dp0` resolves to the full path of the folder in which the batch script resides.

Comment: Actually this resolves to something like `C:\myDir\\bin\Iris.exe` (note the double-backslash). This still works but leaving away the backslash before bin seems to be "cleaner"? --> `%~dp0bin\Iris.exe`.

Comment: @mozzbozz If you can guarantee that `%~dp0` will always have a trailing backslash both statements will work. Otherwise the one with the additional backslash is the safer variant.

Comment: Ok, that's a point. I've only tested this on two different Windows 7 machines, might be different elsewhere (XP, Vista oder Windwos 8 --> I don't know but: Microsoft logic and I couldn't find any docs about it ;)). However, I found that I had to put quotation marks around it (`"%~dp0\bin\Iris.exe"`) as the path had a whitespace in it :) Just to be *really* sure it works on every computer.

Comment: you can ensure there's backslash with `SET "scriptdir=%~dp0"` and  on the next line `IF NOT "%scriptdir:~-1%"=="\" SET "scriptdir=%scriptdir%\"`. I've seen incidents where double backslash in middle of the path breaks software.

Answer (score 54):

You can get all the required file properties by using the code below:

```
FOR %%? IN (file_to_be_queried) DO (
    ECHO File Name Only       : %%~n?
    ECHO File Extension       : %%~x?
    ECHO Name in 8.3 notation : %%~sn?
    ECHO File Attributes      : %%~a?
    ECHO Located on Drive     : %%~d?
    ECHO File Size            : %%~z?
    ECHO Last-Modified Date   : %%~t?
    ECHO Parent Folder        : %%~dp?
    ECHO Fully Qualified Path : %%~f?
    ECHO FQP in 8.3 notation  : %%~sf?
    ECHO Location in the PATH : %%~dp$PATH:?
)
```

Comment: How to get relative path from absolute path?

Answer (score 37):

I have found that `%CD%` gives the path the script was called from and not the path of the script, however, `%~dp0` will give the path of the script itself.

Answer (score 17):

You should be able to use the current directory

> "%CD%"\bin\Iris.exe

Comment: This fails when the current directory isn't `Program`, this will happen when you double click the `run.bat` from the explorer. `%CD%` is the current directory `%~dp0` is the directory of the batch file itself

Comment: That will not happen when you double click the batch file from Explorer, because Explorer runs things with the current directory set to the containing directory. The only exception is shortcuts, where you can manually change the directory in which the shortcut is started; but even there the default value is the containing folder of the shortcut's destination i.e. equivalent to `%~dp0`.

The failure scenario for using a relative path like this is when the batch file is run manually, or from another batch file (or program).

Answer (score 6):

either
`bin\Iris.exe`
(no leading slash - because that means start right from the root)
or `\Program\bin\Iris.exe` (full path)

Comment: bin\Iris.exe it is not working :( I don't like to use root, because someday maybe I will move this dir to an other location. 
And what if I ask from the OS the current absolute path? and I will use that to start exe in bin?

Comment: I assumed the current drive would be the USB stick's drive, and current folder would be `\Program` - is that not the case? You can show that with a simple `cd` command in the line before you try to run the .exe

Comment: Simply using a relative path won't necessarily work. The path will be relative to the current working directory, which may be different from the parent directory of `run.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
%~dp0 will return the drive and the path
so try two things
%~dp0 --> will give ..F:\Program\run.bat
now inside the .bat file if we want to access exe then use below
pushd "%~dp0" 
..\bin\Iris.exe 

Explanation
-->PUSHD command to get the directory of the batch script file in the Windows operating system.
-->while %CD% can be used on command line.
for %CD%, the current directory means the directory when executing the command line or the batch file. So if you put the batch file in c:\dir\test.bat --> @echo %CD%, if you are now in C:\dir and execute test.bat, it will output c:\dir;

-->%~dp0 can only be used in bat file 
For %~dp0, the current directory is the directory where the bat file resides. In above example - the output is the same: c:\dir\. Note there is a back slash at the end.
Hope this helps!
```