# Batch file to move files to another directory

Tags: file, batch-file, move

I hope that you can help me with this one. It might have been asked multiple times already (I know that), but for some reason, I just can't have it working.

I want to move some files from the "files" directory to the root directory.

So the files are, for example:

```
test1.txt test2.txt test3.zip test4.zip test5.exe test6.exe
```

I want these files to be moved to different directories.

So I'm using something like this:

```
move files\*.txt ..\txt /q
move files\*.zip ..\zip /q
move files\*.exe ..\exe /q
```

But I always get errors. It can't find the files and then the CMD stops working.

Thanks.

EDIT:

It's working like this:

```
move /y .\files\*.txt ..\txt
move /y .\files\*.zip ..\zip
move /y .\files\*.exe ..\exe
```

But now it won't move the file to the parent directory.

Comment: What's the current working directory?

Comment: C:/test for this one.

Comment: `the root directory.` -- `to different directories` whereto??
`But I always get errors` message??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

/q isn't a valid parameter.
/y: Suppresses prompting to confirm overwriting

Also ..\txt means directory txt under the parent directory, not the root directory.
The root directory would be: \
And please mention the error you get

Try:

```
move files\*.txt \
```

Edit:
Try:

```
move \files\*.txt \
```

Edit 2:

```
move C:\files\*.txt C:\txt
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I already fixed that, I'm using /y now. There is no error, it just can't find the files but they do exist in the "files" directory. And yes, I want to move them to the folders on the parent directory.

Comment: Try:    move    \files\ *.txt    \  [I updated the reply, since it doesn't display properly here]

Comment: No, it keeps saying that I can't find the files.

Comment: try the full path: move C:\files\ *.txt C:\ , make sure it contains files *.txt and that they aren't hidden.

Comment: As I mentioned before: ..\txt isn't the parent directory. It is txt directory under the parent directory. Is this what you need? Is there txt directory under parent directory?

Comment: Haha, yes, that is what I need. Sorry for the bad English, its not always like that, it's just that I'm doing so many things at the moment.

Comment: I will, could you just help me with the last step? I need to move .txt files to the "txt" folder on the parent directory.

Comment: This should do it: move /y .\files\*.txt \txt  But make sure txt folder already exists

Comment: Thanks, that did work. Is there anyway that I can move the files to the txt folder on the parent directory without specifing the full directory?

Comment: ..\txt should work. But this means you are already in the files folder(since the parent is the root).

Comment: For some reason ..\txt does not work. And for the upvote I need 15 reputation, sorry.

Comment: OK. Just make sure about the current directory. It must be files.

Comment: Haha, thanks. I did a cd files and now its working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there's a file `test.txt` in Root Folder, and want to move it to `\TxtFolder`,

You can try

```
move %~dp0\test.txt %~dp0\TxtFolder
```

.

reference answer: [relative path in BAT script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936625/relative-path-in-bat-script)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
move "C:\files\*.txt" "C:\txt"
```