# batch script move files with the same extension, not on parent-sub path to another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244345/batch-file-to-move-files-to-another-directory)

I want to move ( not copy) files with a specific extension to another folder which is not a sub or the parent. The hierarchy is as follows

[image]

I need the path to be relative, file names unknown,
The batch file will be in the same folder "source" , the files I want to move all are of a particular extension.

I have tried this in a .bat file:

```
move cd %~dp0\*.txt cd %~dpi\dest
```

as well as this

```
move  %~dp0\*.txt %~dpi\dest
```

and this

```
move  %~dp0\*.txt %~dp0\dest
```

I have also tried running the .bat when it is in the parent folder with

```
move %~dp0\source\*.json %~dp0\dest
```

none give any error, and the files are not moved from the source folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be

```
move *.txt ..\dest
```

if you're standing in source and want to move to dest.