# batch file with relative path and close command prompt

Tags: batch-file

I try this code :

```
start /d "D:\test\CONTOH\DATA\QGIS2\bin\" qgis.bat
```

based on :
[Bat file to run a .exe at the command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221730/bat-file-to-run-a-exe-at-the-command-prompt)

But, I want to be relative path, something like this :

```
start /d %~dp0\DATA\QGIS2\bin\qgis.bat
```

based on :
[relative path in BAT script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936625/relative-path-in-bat-script)

but, nothing happen. So, can someone give me information, what is wrong?

Comment: If you compare your commands you can see that your first command has three arguments after the `start` but your second command only has two

Comment: start takes the first parameter in double quotes as the window title. Insert an empty dummy pair to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command prompt window and run `start /?`. This outputs the help for the command **START** which should be read on using this command to get knowledge about its options.

Run in command prompt window `call /?` and read the output help pages to understand `%~dp0`. The drive and path of the batch file (argument 0) always ends with a backslash. Therefore don't add an extra backslash on concatenating it with another string.

And the first double quoted string is interpreted by **START** as title for the new console window displayed in title bar of the new window. Therefore better specify always a title string which can be also an empty string like `""` in case of starting a GUI application on which no console window is opened at all.

```
start "Running QGIS2" /D "%~dp0DATA\QGIS2\bin" qgis.bat
```

Also possible is using this command line in batch file:

```
start "Running QGIS2" /D"%~dp0DATA\QGIS2\bin" qgis.bat
```

Here *start in directory* as defined with `/D"%~dp0DATA\QGIS2\bin"` is 100% correct specified according to help of command **START** as one parameter string.

But Windows command interpreter accepts also the first variant with just option `/D` without any folder path and next parameter string `"%~dp0DATA\QGIS2\bin"` after a separating space is the folder path for *start in directory*.

The first variant with just `/D` as one parameter string and `"%~dp0DATA\QGIS2\bin"` as one more parameter string is easier to read in comparison to second variant with `/D"%~dp0DATA\QGIS2\bin"` being just one parameter string.